# Ошибка Unknown column '' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Есть какая-то очень странная ошибка, объясните, почему она возникает?

[Вот сама строчка, на которой возникла ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbGrd.png)

[А здесь таблица](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p31Pv.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну всё верно.... вы же знаете когда нужно применять обратные кавычки а когда одинарные? Или везде решили обратные писать?)

Comment: Да ещё вставляете переменные в запрос даже не проверив, есть ли там хоть какое-то значение

Comment: можете пояснить, какие именно здесь применить?

Comment: Применить те, которые правильные

Comment: Прочитатйте в документации когда именно пишутся обратные кавычки и затем посмотрите в код свой ещё раз

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка возникла, так значение переменной $teamname в косых кавычках интерпретировалось как название колонки, а не строковое значение.

Используйте двойные кавычки для строкового литерала, косые кавычки - для выделения названия колонки и одинарные - для константы в SQL-запросе:

```php
$check = mysqli_query(
    $link, 
    "SELECT * FROM sc_platform_users WHERE `teamname` = '{$teamname}'"
) or die("ERROR: " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Но такой способ не защищен от SQL-инъекций, и потому правильней было бы использовать [`PreparedStatement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php):

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM sc_platform_users WHERE `teamname` = ?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $teamname);
$stmt->execute();
$check = $stmt->get_result();
// ...
```

Comment: @avp, У @wololo было рабочее решение, без UB, так что не вижу смысла в восстановлении своего ответа.  Вероятно, проще было действительно воспользоваться квадратным корнем, а для тестирования написать цикл с проверкой-костылём `if (i == INT_MAX) break;`, хотя для меня это выглядит диковато.  Я как-то привык к более определённому поведению :)

Comment: @avp [Does Java have undefined behavior like C++ does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886415/): _In C/C++, "undefined behaviour" means that anything may happen. If you put `int z = x++ + y++;` in your C program, the compiler may decide to generate code that formats you hard drive and it would still be compliant with the standard. There's nothing like that in Java either._ :)

Comment: Да, исключения IntegerOverflowException не будет.  Но в джаве `i * i <= n && i * i > 0` отработает гарантированно, в С -- нет (особенно с опциями оптимизации).

Comment: @avp, Да, красиво!

Comment: Удалил свои комменты